# Lazily traverse collection of functions short-circuiting on first success

Tags: scala, scala-cats

The goal is to lazily evaluate a collection of functions stopping on and returning the first happy result. Computation should be sequential. Here is my attempt

```
def f1(i: Int): Either[String, Int] = {println(s"f1($i)"); Left("boom-f1") }
def f2(i: Int): Either[String, Int] = {println(s"f2($i)"); Left("boom-f2") }
def f3(i: Int): Either[String, Int] = {println(s"f3($i)"); Right(i) }

val in = 42

(f1(in) #:: f2(in) #:: f3(in) #:: Stream.empty) collectFirst { case Right(x) => x } toRight("boom")
```

which outputs

```
f1(42)
f2(42)
f3(42)
res0: Either[String,Int] = Right(42)
```

where we see all three executed, whilst

```
def f1(i: Int): Either[String, Int] = {println(s"f1($i)"); Right(i) }
def f2(i: Int): Either[String, Int] = {println(s"f2($i)"); Right(i) }
def f3(i: Int): Either[String, Int] = {println(s"f3($i)"); Right(i) }
```

would output

```
f1(42)
res0: Either[String,Int] = Right(42)
```

where we see only one executed.

Does cats provide abstraction for such lazy failure-biased traversal?

Comment: Hi Mario, I did not understand, what exactly is the question? How would you have this list of functions? And why exactly do you need cats, isn't just `funList.iterator.map(f => f(in)).collectFirst { case Right(r) => r }` exactly what you need?

Comment: Also note you may use **Views**, **Streams** or **LazyList** instead of **Iterator** in the previous example.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez `Streams` with `collectFirst` indeed works fine. I was just wondering if this pattern is general enough for `cats.implicits._` to provide extension method for it. The semantics here are akin to `orElse`. The key is for functions to evaluate lazily as they are expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Ior](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/ior.html) data type which is an inclusive-or relationship between two data types.

```
import cats.data.Ior
import cats.implicits._

import scala.annotation.tailrec

object Main2 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    def f1(i: Int): Either[String, Int] = {println(s"f1($i)"); Left("boom-f1") }
    def f2(i: Int): Either[String, Int] = {println(s"f2($i)"); Left("boom-f2") }
    def f3(i: Int): Either[String, Int] = {println(s"f3($i)"); Right(i) }

    def traverseLazy(input: Int, list: List[Int => Either[String, Int]]): Ior[List[String], Int] = {
      @tailrec
      def go(ls: List[Int => Either[String, Int]], acc: List[String]): Ior[List[String], Int] = ls match {
        case x :: xs => x(input) match  {
          case Left(error) => go(xs, error :: acc)
          case Right(value) => if (ls.isEmpty) value.rightIor else Ior.both(acc, value)
        }
        case Nil => acc.leftIor
      }

      go(list, List.empty)
    }

    val res = traverseLazy(42, List(f1, f2, f3)).fold(
      _.intercalate("\n"),
      res => s"succeeded with $res",
      (errors, res) => s"completed successfully with res $res but some errors were also found: ${errors.intercalate(", ")}")

    println(res)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah I was overcomplicating, `orElse` already implements such semantics and gives simply

```
f1(in) orElse f2(in) orElse f3(in) orElse Left("boom")
```

as it takes by-name parameter.